# How can I convert utf8 code number to unicode code number in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8

I want to generate all utf8 characters list.
I wrote the code below but it didn't work well.
I thought that because `chr()` expected unicode number, but I gave utf8 code number.
I think I have to convert utf8 code number to unicode code number but I don't know the way.
How can I do? Or do you know better way?

```
def utf8_2byte():
    characters = []
    # first byte range: [C2-DF]
    for first in range(0xC2, 0xDF + 1):
        # second byte range: [80-BF]
        for second in range(0x80, 0xBF + 1):
            num = (first << 8) + second
            line = [hex(num), chr(num)]
            characters.append(line)
    return characters
```

I expect:

```
# UTF8 code number, UTF8 character
[0xc380,À]
[0xc381,Á]
[0xc382,Â]
```

actually:

```
[0xc380,쎀]
[0xc381,쎁]
[0xc382,쎂]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python 3, `chr` takes unicode codepoints, not `utf-8`. `U+C380` is in the Hangul range. Instead you can use `bytearray` for the decode

```
>>> bytearray((0xc3, 0x80)).decode('utf-8')
'À'
```

There are other methods also, like `struct` or `ctypes`. Anything that assembles native bytes and converts them to `bytes` will do.

Comment: Thank you. I understood. Unicode `U+c380` is codepoint. `1100001110000000` (0xc380) is bytearray that was decoded using UTF-8 encoding style from unicode codepoint. 
Your code worked well. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Unicode is a character set while UTF-8 is a encoding which is a algorithm to encode code point from Unicode to bytes in machine level and vice versa.

The code point `0xc380` is `쎀` in the standard of Unicode.

The bytes `0xc380` is `À` when you decode it use UTF-8 encoding.

```
>>> s = "쎀"
>>> hex(ord(s))
'0xc380'
>>> b = bytes.fromhex("C3 80")
>>> b
b'\xc3\x80'
>>> b.decode("utf8")
'À'
>>> bytes((0xc3, 0x80)).decode("utf8")
'À'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I use `bytes()` and `decode()` method.